# Change m2 repository path

Tags: java, maven-3

I have a problem because I would like to change the m2 repository path, I am on linux I have added this `<localRepository>/tmp/m2Repo</localRepository>` in my settings.xml but when I execute the command `mvn archetype:generate` it downloads all the content in the standard path.

when I use the command `mvn archetype:generate -Dmaven.repo.local=/tmp/m2Repo` this command is a success. How can I make for not use the `-Dmaven.repo.local=/tmp/m2Repo` in the command line and success ?

Thank you!

Comment: As a hack, it might help to move the `~/.m2` directory to `/tmp` and add a symlink.

Comment: Are you editing the _{M2_HOME}/conf/settings.xml_ ?

Comment: Where have you located your `settings.xml`? Correctly in `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two locations where settings exist. Please, be sure which one you use. Check the [manual](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html), check files properties.

```
One is Maven install (global), second is inside user account.
The settings element in the settings.xml file contains elements used to define values which configure Maven execution in various ways, like the pom.xml, but should not be bundled to any specific project, or distributed to an audience. These include values such as the local repository location, alternate remote repository servers, and authentication information.

There are two locations where a settings.xml file may live:

    The Maven install: $M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml
    A user’s install: ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml

The former settings.xml are also called global settings, the latter settings.xml are referred to as user settings. If both files exists, their contents gets merged, with the user-specific settings.xml being dominant.

Tip: If you need to create user-specific settings from scratch, it’s easiest to copy the global settings from your Maven installation to your ${user.home}/.m2 directory. Maven’s default settings.xml is a template with comments and examples so you can quickly tweak it to match your needs.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you already checked your conf/settings.xml from your MAVEN_HOME or M2_HOME environment variable?